# Pivoting selected rows into new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I am working with census data in a region. I have the total, urban, and rural populations of each municipality in the region, identified by a municipality code. In my data frame, the three population types are "stacked" in one `population` variable, such that rows containing municipality codes store total populations but not urban or rural ones:

| location | population | mun_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| municipality_1 | 10000 | 1 |
| urban | 6000 | 1 |
| rural | 4000 | 1 |
| municipality_2 | 15000 | 2 |
| urban | 10000 | 2 |
| rural | 5000 | 2 |

I want to construct a second data frame with one variable for each population type:

| location | total_pop | urban_pop | rural_pop | mun_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| municipality_1 | 10000 | 6000 | 4000 | 1 |
| municipality_2 | 15000 | 10000 | 5000 | 2 |

I have tried using `pivot_wider()` from package **tidyr**, but can't seem to get the table to look the way I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a new column based on the 'municipality' substring in the location and reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(grp = case_when(str_detect(location, 'municipality') ~'total_pop', 
  TRUE ~ str_c(location, '_pop')), 
  location = case_when(grp == 'total_pop' ~ location)) %>% 
  fill(location) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = population)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  location       mun_code total_pop urban_pop rural_pop
  <chr>             <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
1 municipality_1        1     10000      6000      4000
2 municipality_2        2     15000     10000      5000
```

#### data

```
df1 <-structure(list(location = c("municipality_1", "urban", "rural", 
"municipality_2", "urban", "rural"), population = c(10000L, 6000L, 
4000L, 15000L, 10000L, 5000L), mun_code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: switched a bit of that code around but it worked! thanks for the easy fix

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace` and `paste` to get the names before `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(loc = paste0(replace(location, grepl("municipality", location), "total"), "_pop"),
         location = paste0("municipality_", mun_code)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = loc, values_from = population)
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  location       mun_code total_pop urban_pop rural_pop
  <chr>             <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
1 municipality_1        1     10000      6000      4000
2 municipality_2        2     15000     10000      5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, your long format data isn't coded properly: **1.** the `municipality_` levels in  `location` shouldn't be named differently depending on location, call them `total` as they are already identified in `mun_code`, and **2.** if you want `mun_code` also as a `factor`, then make one.

```
muns <- grep('municipality_', dat$location)
dat$location[muns] <- 'total'

dat$municipality <- factor(dat$mun_code, labels=paste0('municipality_', unique(dat$mun_code)))

dat
#   location population mun_code   municipality
# 1    total      10000        1 municipality_1
# 2    urban       6000        1 municipality_1
# 3    rural       4000        1 municipality_1
# 4    total      15000        2 municipality_2
# 5    urban      10000        2 municipality_2
# 6    rural       5000        2 municipality_2
```

Then it's just

```
reshape(dat, idvar='mun_code', timevar='location', v.names='population', direction='wide')
#   mun_code   municipality population.total population.urban population.rural
# 1        1 municipality_1            10000             6000             4000
# 4        2 municipality_2            15000            10000             5000
```

or whatever fancy package you want to use to [reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/6574038) your data.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(location = c("municipality_1", "urban", "rural", 
"municipality_2", "urban", "rural"), population = c(10000L, 6000L, 
4000L, 15000L, 10000L, 5000L), mun_code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```